# Installing the Enthought Python Distribution with existing python distro

Tags: python, installation, ipython, sage, enthought

I am currently trying to install the Enthought Python Distribution (EPD), and have existing python distros. I currently have `ipython`, `numpy` and a lot of other tools, plus Sage (an open-source Python science/math distro) installed.

When I tried installing EPD, I tried testing it from `ipython` with `import pandas`, which is included in the EPD. This gave me an error. **How do I make EPD my default python distro?**

My `$PATH` is this: `Users/scott/.zcm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin`

My `$PYTHONPATH` is currently empty.

Edit: I have also installed ZSH, am running a Mac, and a whole bunch more stuff. It turns out the problem was with ZSH. In my `.zshrc` I had to add this: `export $PATH=/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/bin:$PATH` The `/Library/...` was added *before* the rest of the `$PATH`.

Comment: Could you include the entire contents of the error which you were shown?

Comment: I was shown no error. But, I found the solution and updated the question.

Comment: You still say " This gave me an error.", what error did it show you? If you have now solved this, then you should add the solution as an answer (and accept it) rather than editing the question. :)

Comment: Will do! And it just didn't work, so it's my bad for saying I got an error.

Answer (score 1):

I have also installed ZSH, am running a Mac, and a whole bunch more stuff.

It turns out the problem was with ZSH, in my `.zshrc` I had to add this:

```
export $PATH=/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/bin:$PATH
```

The `/Library/...` was added before the rest of the `$PATH`.